# send and delete a record from a sqlite DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to send a record from database to server and then delete it. This is my code for sending and deleting in service.

```
      DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        Cursor cursor=db.getAllData();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                jObject = new JSONObject();
                jObject.put("Imei", cursor.getString(1));
                jObject.put("Lat", cursor.getString(2));
                jObject.put("Long", cursor.getString(3));
                jObject.put("Gpsdatetime", cursor.getString(4));
                jObject.put("Speed", cursor.getString(5));
                jObject.put("Altitude",cursor.getString(6));
                jObject.put("Battery", cursor.getString(7));
                //jArray.put(jObject);

                String datatoServer = jObject.toString()+"\n";
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datatoServer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                HttpEntity entity;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String url = "http://url";
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(datatoServer);
                se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
                entity = se;
                request.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                entity = response.getEntity();
                db.deleteContacts(1);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }//if
        db.close();
```

I am confused with the delete function. the data is send to server properly but it deletes only 1st row.

here is the delete function in my DBHelper class.Which takes rowid as parameter.

```
public boolean deleteContacts(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+"="+rowId, null)>0;
}
```

Comment: **db.deleteContacts(1);** is not this suppose to delete the 1st row? what 1 means as parameter?

Comment: yup 1 is the row_id. hence its deleting 1st row only. but i am not getting what to write to delete all rows as soon as they are send to server.

Comment: can u post your deleteContacts method??

Comment: @Manasi, you have passed 1 as static value, so each time it will look for 1st record and try to delete it, which is correct for first time but from the 2nd time it can't find & delete the 1st record as it has been deleted already.

Comment: Thanks lucifer. and sory if I am asking silly questions

Comment: is your row id always 1 ??

Comment: I was assuming that each time I delete 1st row the 2nd row ll automatically become the 1st 1. Is it so.

Comment: no... id will not change.. if row with id 1 is deleted, another row will not be created with id = 1

Comment: nop my row id is autoincremented. what should i pass instead of 1 to delete the row immediately after sending to server.

Comment: in db.getalldata get the id of the row too.. and then pass that value to db.deleteContacts();

Answer (score 0):

if `db.deleteContacts(1);` deletes first row then you can put an int variable inside your `do...while()` loop and provide it an increment of 1 on each iteration. Then execute `db.deleteContacts(your_var)`.

Comment: db.deleteContacts(cursor.getLong(0));

Comment: can i write like this db.deleteContacts(cursor.getLong(0));

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.deleteContacts(1);
```

Problem is here you are sending 1 as argument to the your method. so it always look for that one having 1 as `rowId`

Use `cursor.getLong(columnIndex)`
 for getting the long value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `db.getAllData()` method selects all columns (including the `id` column`, change...

```
db.deleteContacts(1);
```

to...

```
db.deleteContacts(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID)));
```

Never assume any given column data is at any fixed column index - find the index using the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```